# flask-sqlalchemy group_by with max id

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a table like this
[image]

Now I want to get data which ip is uniq and id is max.

```
In [53]: ModuleInfo.query.group_by(ModuleInfo.ip).all()
Out[53]:
[<ModuleInfo 1>,
 <ModuleInfo 5>,
 <ModuleInfo 14>,
 <ModuleInfo 16>,
 <ModuleInfo 20>,
 <ModuleInfo 17>,
 <ModuleInfo 28>,
 <ModuleInfo 27>]
```

retuan values are not max id, I want to `ip:127.0.0.1`->`id:4`, I use order_by id, but it just reverse the list.

And when I try to use `distinct`, I found it not work:

```
In [51]: ModuleInfo.query.distinct(ModuleInfo.ip).all()
Out[51]:
[<ModuleInfo 1>,
 <ModuleInfo 2>,
 <ModuleInfo 3>,
 <ModuleInfo 4>,
 <ModuleInfo 5>,
 <ModuleInfo 6>,
 <ModuleInfo 7>,
 <ModuleInfo 14>,
 <ModuleInfo 15>,
 <ModuleInfo 16>,
 <ModuleInfo 17>,
 <ModuleInfo 18>,
 <ModuleInfo 19>,
 <ModuleInfo 20>,
 <ModuleInfo 21>,
 <ModuleInfo 22>,
 <ModuleInfo 23>,
 <ModuleInfo 24>,
 <ModuleInfo 25>,
 <ModuleInfo 26>,
 <ModuleInfo 27>,
 <ModuleInfo 28>,
 <ModuleInfo 29>,
 <ModuleInfo 30>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
foo = Session.query(func.max(ModuleInfo.id),ModuleInfo.ip).\
    group_by(ModuleInfo.ip).order_by(ModuleInfo.ip).all()
```

I used declarative base and scoped Session to run a test here but the idea is the same. You should receive a list of tuples with (max(id), ip) as a result.

Hannu

Comment: I had tried this way, but I want to get the model entities

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions in where clauses, which sort of indicates you need two queries. One to extract the ID:s as explained above, and another to query the whole ModuleInfo objects based on this set of ids.